# Upload and save mp4 files in database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added in mime file:

```
'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp'),
```

still not able to upload files. Not showing any errors also.

Any idea how to upload all types of files in codeigniter through form

Comment: you want a .mp4 file to be saved in a database?

Comment: Do you _really_ want to store audio files in database? If not sure, then use file-system to store files (images, audios, videos, etc) and in database keep reference to them (e.g., path to a file).

Answer (score 3):

Hi just add your mime type to
**application/config/mimes**

```
 'mp4' =>'video/mp4'
  '3gp'=>'video/3gpp'
```

then just add each one individually in the allowed types

[Link for all the mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

Comment: Actually size issue I am facing. If video is of small size around 900kb then it is getting uploaded. but if video zise is larger then giving problem.

Comment: @AartiBorole is that the case with any kind of file or is it only the case with mp4's  ? Also you should check your php.ini for any filesize limits and as well remember when you initiate the function that the size is in KB

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing the right thing by checking the extension and the file type as well! For instance, if your file name is **video.mp4**, your file type is probably **video/mp4** but not necessarily! (I was just dealing with a **.m4a** file and my audio type is **audio/mp4**.)

You can test the correct file type by printing it out for yourself after an upload.

```
echo $_FILES[0]['file_type'];
```

After that, you can add the following line to the **mimes.php** config file:

```
$mimes['<your extension>'] = '<your file type>';
```

Alternatively, if you encounter multiple MIME types for the same extension, you can add an array instead:

```
$mimes['<your extension>'] = array('<your file type 1>', '<your file type 2>');
```

I hope this helps!